# VS code jupyter notebook "умное автозаполнение" не работает

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, intellisense

проблема заключается в том, что при работе с кодом в jupiter notebook в vs code не появляются подсказки по ключам словарей в новых ячейках, хотя раньше работали корректно. На данный момент работают подсказки только со строкой-цифрой, ни на кириллицу, ни на латиницу, ни на обычные числа подсказки не всплывают. Я говорю о подсказка, когда пишешь dict['

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно по стриншотам работает автозаполнение только в текущей ячейке

Answer (score 0):

Новая версия расширения Pylance "2024.1.104 (1 February 2024) PreRelease" нарушает зависимости, поэтому в jupyter notebook некорректно отображаются ключи словарей и т.д.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]